# How to only fetch fields of a Mongoose discriminator base model?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a base model for all the users in our system, called `User`. I also have a `Self` model to hold the properties of the user that should only be accessable for the current user (e.g., the email address, because it's private). `Self` is a discriminator and inherits from `User`.

```
const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema<IMongooseUser>({ username: String, ... });
export const User = mongoose.model('User', userSchema);

const selfSchema = new mongoose.Schema<IMongooseSelf>({ email: String, ... });
export const Self = User.discriminator('Self', selfSchema);
```

All of my users in the DB are therefore has `__t: 'Self'`, so when I use `User.findOne()` it returns all the `Self` fields as well. Is there a way to force Mongoose to only return the base `User` fields?

My solution atm is using `new User({ ...user, __t: 'User' })` (where `user` is the return value of `User.findOne().lean()`), however this is a very manual solution. Is there a better one? Maybe an option that I can change?

I'm open to other ways in which I could enforce private fields not to be returned from a document.

Answer (score 1):

You can exclude Self properties in your projection...
Example;

```
const res = await User.findOne({username:"test"}, "-email").exec();
console.log(res)
```

Result;

```
{
  _id: new ObjectId("62da6c9e81f12d914120c702"),
  username: 'test',
  __t: 'Self',
  __v: 0
}
```